# Bash Scripts (even trivial ones) stuck when invoked on the terminal

Tags: bash, shell

I have a server on which we execute multiple bash scripts to automate tasks (like copying files to other servers, kicking off backups, etc). It has been working for some months, but today it started to get erratic.

What is happening, is that the script gets 'stuck' for a while, and after that, it runs with no problem. If I copy and paste the commands one by one on the terminal, it works, so is not something on the script itself, but it seems something that is preventing the bash interpreter (if that makes sense).

Another weird behavior is that the same script will run with no issues eventually. However, as we use Jenkins for automation, the scripts are re-created every time a new job starts.

For example, I created a new script, tst.sh, which only contains an echo. If I try to run it directly, it gets stuck for a while. I tried to debug it with `bash -xeav` but it does not print my script code, which means that it is not reading it. After a while, the script ran, with no changes. However, creating one script, with the same content and a different name, resurfaces the issue.

My hypothesis is that something prevents the script to be read, and just waits until whatever is blocking it to finish. However, I did not see any process holding the file, which means that it may not the case.

Is there any other thing I should try? My knowledge in bash is pretty basic, so I don't know if there is a flag that may help me on debugging this internally.

I am working on RHEL 8.85, the bash version is GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

**UPDATES BASED ON THE COMMENTS**

1. Server resources are OK, no usage for them.
2. Hardware for the server also works fine, the ops team has not reached out with any known issue at least
3. Reboot makes the issue disappear, however, it reappears after 5 minutes or so
4. The issue seems that is not related to bash profiles and such.

Comment: Hate to ask this, because it's obvious .. But -- have you restarted the server?  Also if these are run by cron .. Have you checked the cron logs/mail for any clues?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the server, maybe disk errors.

Comment: Concur, check the journal (or syslog if RH still uses that) and see what other problems are occurring. Other than straight-up hardware/disk/RAID error, the only other thing that comes to mind is memory exhaustion and paging from swap. Also remember, on disk space exhaustion, `root` has a small margin of additional usable space while users would be prevented from using new storage.

Comment: @Zak yes, server restart worked for a while, but the issue appeared again after some hours. The jobs are executed with Jenkins, checking the logs only shows where the script is invoked, but not execution is performed.

Comment: @Barmar I think that may be the case as well, working with the ops team on that front, but wanted to discard software first.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Checked memory, and it has enough to work with. The scripts are not that heavy, they mostly call APIs and such, so the actual server does not work that much. Disk space has about 34% usage, and should not present any issue on exhaustion.

Comment: If there are no hardware or other issues in the journal, you have disk space and RAM available, then last guess would be you have a program running that is misbehaving and is either stuck in a loop saturating all CPU cores, or corrupting a a large allocation virtual memory giving the memory manager fits. I'd check with `top` and `ps axf` and see if that identifies any culprit. Otherwise, I hate to say it, but give it the Windows 1-solution for all.... reboot.

Comment: The symptoms are close to what happens when a *clever* antimalware decides to analyze any new code and submits it to a remote server for that. I had a good time removing such a thing from my last Windows box...

Comment: For the safe side, you could try a `bash --noprofile --norc -c "echo xxx"`. If it stucks too, you know at least that this is not related to your startup files. Another test would be to do a simple command with another shell (ksh, zsh, ....), to see whether the behaviour is particular to bash.

Comment: Either way, we need a [mre] to be able to provide any authoritative answer. That said, it would do a lot of good to use `strace -f` or similar to watch _where_ things hang. If it's an `execve()` syscall, that does indeed smell a lot like Serge's suggestion. (If you have root, `sysdig` is a much broader / more powerful tool, and if the component at fault has userspace pieces, there's a very good chance sysdig will see their operation).

Comment: Update for today: As @CharlesDuffy and others suggested, after going over the DevOps team that owns the server, it seems that there is security software that is blocking stuff from running. Still under investigation, but most likely, the culprit is there. Tools like `strace -f` also get stuck when executing, so I was not able to confirm the system calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, posting this as an answer so people can find it quicker.

Turns out, as multiple users suggested in the comments (thanks to all!!) the problem was caused by a security monitor, which analyzed each of the scripts that were executed. The team changed some settings on that end to prevent it from happening, and so far is working.